# How do I start with PHP apache setup for testing my PHP/HTML files?

Tags: apache2, html, testing

I haven’t coded PHP in 15 years, and I can't remember how to get started. I set up PHP 8.1 with apache2 on my Ubuntu 22.04 desktop, but I don’t recall how/where to set up my files and how to test them in a web browser. For example if I made a traditional hello.html (with php echo embedded) see below, how do I get it into my web browser to see if it works? It currently sits in my home folder.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>title</title>
    <!-- link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" -->
    <!-- <script src="script.js"></script -->
  </head>
  <body>
    <!-- page content -->
        <?php
    phpinfo();
    ?>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Put it in `/var/www/html`, start your apache server (`sudo systemctl start apache2`), and then visit http://localhost/hello.php.